# Should I reduce not required columns in DFs before join them in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

Is there any sense to reduce not required columns before I join it in Spark data frames?
For example:
DF1 has 10 columns, DF2 has 15 columns, DF3 has 25 columns.
I want to join them, select needed 10 columns and save it in .parquet.

Does it make sense to transform DFs with select only needed columns before the join or Spark engine will optimize the join by itself and will not operate with all 50 columns during the join operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it makes a perfect sense because it reduce the amount of data shuffled between executors. And it's better to make selection of only necessary columns as early as possible - in most cases, if file format allows (Parquet, Delta Lake), Spark will read data only for necessary columns, not for all columns. I.e.:

```py
df1 = spark.read.parquet("file1") \
  .select("col1", "col2", "col3")
df2 = spark.read.parquet("file2") \
  .select("col1", "col5", "col6")
joined = df1.join(df2, "col1")
```

Comment: Thanks. 
So if data frames are read from CSV - it makes sense to select needed columns as early as possible.
But if data frames are read from parquet or delta - it does not make sense and Spark will do it instead of me automatically. 
Right?

Comment: No, exactly opposite. When you read CSV, you still need to read the whole file to extract data. But parquet is a columnar format, so if you specify a list of columns to read, then only these columns will be read. Please note that if you do select after join, it may not affect reading of only specific columns

Comment: OK, got it. I thought that probably Spark does not read columns from parquet DFs if I do not select them after join but before any action (i. e. writing or display).
So anyway if I am going to join parquet DFs the best practice is selecting of required columns before join function.

Comment: Join is a stage, and predicate pushdown across stages could be tricky

Comment: It makes perfect sense to me to remove unused columns before joining data, but do you have a link to literature supporting this practice? I couldn't find any resource.

Comment: that's just experience and knowledge of how Spark works